# What is the google smtp service similar to amazon ses, is it gmail smtp?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, smtp, cloud, smtpclient

What is the google smtp service similar to amazon ses, is it gmail smtp? I have used amazon ses smtp for sending marketing emails, by configuring in my server. So google has similar service, or is it same as smtp.gmail.com?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Google Cloud does not offer a service similar to Amazon SES.

If your goal is to send promotional, marketing or newsletter type emails, use a service such as MailChimp or SendGrid.

If your goal is to send emails as part of your service to internal users or a small number of select users, use a service such as Gmail, G Suite or Office 365.

Comment: @Greg My answer includes two services. There are many services to use to send emails to thousands of users.